# Storing Key of TreeMap in Value (java)

Tags: java, oop, treemap

`TreeMap`s are instantiated by `Key, Value` pairs.  For me, the `Key` is an IP address, and the `Value`s are objects that contain stats about that IP address.

Is there ever a reason to redundantly store the the `Key` inside the `Value` object?  I'm tempted to save space and leave it out, but intuitively it feels wrong not to have the `Key` inside the object (for good encapsulation).

Comment: can you explain more pleas?

Comment: that depends purely on usage of `Value` object. When iterating through map you'll end up with `Entry<Key, Value>`. The question is, do you need `Value` object to contain `Key` further in your app?

Comment: In your particular case, key inside the object would make a lot of sense. I would only save space if the system was running out of memory or something similiar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your design is flawed - you're in "object denial".

You should create a class to hold the details, including the IP address.

If you then want fast retrieval of the details given an IP address, you could store them in a Map using the IP address as the key.

In a way, this is what you're asking, because the key being used in the map is stored in the value object. It's just that with the proper design, the key is already part of the object stored in the value.

Comment: If I call `mytreemap.put(packet.ip, packet)` what is being stored in each Red-Black tree node?  Two object references?

Comment: The more I think about it, I think you must be right.  Indeed my ip addresses are `int` but I have to declare `TreeMap<Integer, Packet>()` (ie, use the class wrapper) because the tree is likely storing a reference to `Integer`.  I think this thing is gonna be slow... :)

Comment: It won't be slow. But `HashMap` is faster for retrieval. You only use a `TreeMap` if you want a *sorted* map. `HashMap` is the fastest retrieval map: It should only take a few *microseconds* to find the key and return the object.

Comment: I have to output the IP addrs in sorted order, so I chose `TreeMap`.  Of course I'm using `int` for IPv4 addrs, and Java doesn't have `unsigned`, so I'm either going to have to write a comparator or hack the tree traversal to start at 0, then do the negatives.  Blah.

Comment: If the output in sorted order is to only be done once, and speed is a concern, you might still want to use a HashMap. but write special code for that one iteration stage.  e.g. List<Integer> `ipList = new ArrayList<Integer>(theHashMap.keySet());  ipList .sort(myHackedComparator);` then iterate over ipList.

Comment: @user949300 You think this is superior to just using the same comparator in the `TreeMap` constructor?  Or just iterating from 0 to maxint, then from minint to 0?

Comment: @Fixee Not sure, but, depending on the exact situation, it might be.  If there are a gazillion puts and gets, and only one final iteration, HashMap could be faster, despite the more complex iteration.  Is there some way you can test on a small subset of the input data?

Answer (score 3):

Bear in mind that including the key will only increase the size of your value object by 32 bits or by 64 bits (depending on whether you're using a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM), so the decision as to whether to include it will probably not have a significant impact on your program's memory consumption - therefore I would err on the side of including it rather than on the side of not including it.

Comment: Your answer also assumes IPv4.  My objects are 64 bits each (32 bit IP address, 32 bit associated info), and there are millions of them.  But if @Bohemian is right, storing them inside or out has no effect on memory consumption.

Comment: @Fixee You're thinking of structs, but Java only has objects - if you include your IP object in a field in another object, then the containing object only holds a reference to the IP object, and the reference's size will be 32-bits on a 32-bit JVM or a 64-bit JVM using compressed pointers assuming a heap size less than 4gb, and which will be 64-bits on a 64-bit JVM without compressed pointers.  The size of the IP object isn't relevant when determining the size of the containing object.

Comment: You're right, of course.  I'm a `C` programmer and Java is a "one web search per line of code" language for me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there ever a reason to redundantly store the the Key inside the Value object?

First of all, you wouldn't be storing the key "inside" the value object.  Rather, the value object would have a reference to the key object.  So you are not storing a redundant copy at all.  (Or at least, not unless you are deliberately copying / cloning the key objects ... which would be rather silly.)

The only question is whether the reference to the key in the value object is "redundant".  In a sense it is, but the flip-side is that redundancy is likely to simplify your code ... and potentially make it more efficient in other places.  We can't make a judgement on that without looking at how these objects are used (elsewhere) in your code.  But the chances are that it doesn't make much difference anyway; see below.

> I'm tempted to save space and leave it out, but intuitively it feels wrong not to have the Key inside the object (for good encapsulation).

The space saving in not having a reference to the key in the value is one word (32 or 64 bit) per value.  This is *most likely* too small to worry about, even if you have millions of these objects.  The reality is that the one extra word it is likely to be *less than 5%* of the overall per-object space usage for a given key + value + map entry.  That 5% is unlikely to make a significant difference ...

The issue of encapsulation is context dependent.  It really depends where the encapsulation boundaries are, and how porous they can be.  Encapsulation isn't an end goal.  It is one of a set of "tools" that can be used in designing / implementing maintainable software.  It is not always the right tool, and it certainly has to be used appropriately; i.e. with a clear understanding of how it helps (or hinders) with the problem at hand.

But here's an idea: you could make the "value" objects both the key and the value in the `Map` ... and use a `Comparator`.  Depending on the details, that would allow you to hide the IP address (etc) entirely within the encapsulation boundary. (That approach won't work with a `HashMap` though ...)

---

Final piece of advice.

You seem to be doing what experienced developers would recognize as "premature optimization".  This is usually a bad idea.  My advice is to stop worrying about the space usage for now.

- Wait until you've got the application working, and you are in a position to benchmark with *real* input data.
- Benchmark and see if the performance (i.e. memory usage) is acceptable.
- If (and only if) it is unacceptable, profile the application to look for opportunities to reduce memory usage.
- Implement and rerun the benchmark to see if it has made a difference.
- Repeat as required.

Comment: With all due respect (and gratitude), this is a single-use program that will scan a multi-gigabyte log and generate a bunch of reports.  I already possess the single input file (a `pcap`) so that is the "live" data.  I'm projecting 28 hours given the current speed of my code, which is horrible.  So I'm trying to optimize as I design rather than later as you suggest.  The speed problem has to do with KMP on byte arrays (since you can't pattern search byte arrays natively in Java).

Comment: If 28 hours is an unacceptably long time, I suggest you apply my approach ... with a time box on the time you spend on optimizing.  But for a once-off job, I'd be inclined to forget it.  But either way, I very much doubt that your jiggling with the key/value types is going to make much difference to the projected 28 hour time.  I think you are looking in the wrong place.  And THAT is the real problem of premature optimization.  Until you benchmark / profile, you are only GUESSING where the real bottlenecks will be, and your attempted optimizations could be a total waste of time.

Comment: The OP question on key/values was more of a "how to think like an OO programmer" question; it was not part of my optimization efforts.  As I said before, I know where the time is being spent: I'm scanning for HTTP headers in a `pcap` file using KMP on a byte array.  It's written in Java and slooow.  It's 92% of the total runtime, but I'm not going to rewrite in C for a one-time job.

Comment: Well one answer to the "how to think like an OO programmer" is DON'T waste your time on fruitless (C-think) things like how to save memory.  Besides, I've addressed the "encapsulation" and "redundancy" parts of your Question above.  And if you want to figure out why your Java is *sloooowww*, then the answer is to profile it.  Chances are that it is something unexpected ... and that there is a good chance you can fix it.  (For instance, by using buffered I/O or by an algorithmic redesign.)

Answer (score 0):

If the key will be used anywhere else in your application along if the value object, then it is a good idea to keep it inside the object